# LibGDX dual assets setup, Eclipse, Gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I have decided to use two different sets of assets for desktop and android but I am not sure what the best way to do this would be? If anyone got some tip or suggestion on how to streamline this I would appreciate it!

I am using Eclipse and Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different assets folders. No one is forcing you to share assets for all platforms.

In `build.gradle` of Android project you can locate and modify `assets.srcDirs = ['assets']` line. It stores a relative path to the assets folder. Since you want to keep separate assets for mobiles (or at least the Android version), I suggest you leave it as it is, though - just keep the `android/assets` folder as usual and store mobile assets there.

As for the desktop project, assets are referenced two times in `build.gradle`: in `project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");` and `linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/android/assets'`. As you can see, they both store (sorta) relative paths that you can safely replace. Creating a new `desktop/assets` folder makes sense if you want to keep a similar folder structure. These two lines would be simply replaced with `project.ext.assetsDir = new File("assets");` and `linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/desktop/assets'` - and then you can just import the project as usual.

Note that this answer assumes that you generated your project with the default `gdx-setup` app. The default LibGDX project generator usually does *not* handle assets folder linking for you, so just remember to mark the new `desktop/assets` folder as resource in Eclipse.